# Overview books on high school topics

Tags: book-recommendation

I have been self studying higher maths, but for the next 3 years I have to get the maximum note in high school and want some books that will make sure I don't fail at that. I used to not study anything at all for school, when I didn't know anything I just thought hard and could get a good note without any problem. However, I am a bit concerned since there are notations I don't know(for example, in logic).

I would like suggestions to cover the following topics, but that won't take me much time, I just need to review somethings. I think I could say I am asking for reference books, but I am not sure.

Topics:
Logic (De Morgan's laws, symbology, negation, disjunction, etc. Commutative and associative properties of disjunction, etc.)
Set Theory (well, for this one I thought of Halmo's book, since it's very affordable and this may be my worst point)
Algebra (Monotial powers, denominator rationalization, rational exponents, Ruffini's law, etc.)
Analytic Geometry (Cartesian Equation of circumference, Cartesian inequations, vectorial calculus in plain, analytic geometry in space, vectorial calculus in space)
Real Functions of Real Variables
Statistics (ok, I am pretty sure I know absolutely everything they will teach, but as I said before it's always good to review)

Besides that, the following year I will have the following:
Geometry in plain and space (I would like a good book on non Euclidean geometry, I will buy also Hartshorne's Euclid and Beyond)
Real Series ((1+1/n)^n for example)

And that's it, I will have also Introduction to Differential Calculus, but this I am already studying and don't need a review book or anything like that. Any doubt I have I can get back to the books I already have.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into Schaum's Outlines in these areas? They are cheap and you can find used copies too. Also, do you have a local college or university where you can check out books?

Comment: @Moo I have a library with some schaum's outline books, in fact, though it has only 3 or 4, but certainly can help me, since I actually just need to review some contents I already know. Thank you for the suggestion.